# Stack Solve solutions in a loop

Tags: equation-solving, replacement, procedural-programming

I want to solve the following equation in a loop:

```
m={{Indexed[c, {1, 1}], 0, Indexed[c, {1, 3}], 0}, {0, 
  Indexed[c, {2, 2}], 0, Indexed[c, {1, 3}]}, {0, -Indexed[c, {2, 2}],
   0, -Indexed[c, {1, 3}]}, {Indexed[c, {1, 1}], 
  0, -Indexed[c, {1, 3}], 0}}

For[n = 1, n < 5, n++,
 v = m[[All, n]];
 sol = Solve[v . Transpose[v] == 1][[2]][[1]];
 Print[sol]
 ]
```

Is there a way to stack all the Solve outputs in only one replacement list such as `Rules={sol[1],sol[2],sol[3],sol[4]}`

Comment: Try: `Reap[
  For[n = 1, n < 5, n++, v = m[[All, n]];
   Sow[Solve[v . Transpose[v] == 1][[2]][[1]]];
   ]][[2, 1]]`